# How do I match the first character in string, AFTER a certain character?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I want to match the first character AFTER a hyphen. See below.

Language: PHP or JavaScript.

example:

> my-first-name

I want to match the characters

**f** and **n**

thanks!

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention that. JavaScript.

Comment: questions says that "you want to match the first character in string, AFTER a certain character?" and detail says "I want to match the characters f and n".. what exectly you want?

Comment: What if you have the character multiple times: `a--b`, `a---b`? Also, do you need a PHP or JavaScript solution?

Comment: No, rule those exceptions out. We're expecting stuff-like-this-only. And either one is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive lookbehind is the way to go, but you probably want

`(?<=-).`

or

`(?<=-)[^-]`

(if you want to avoid capturing '-' in strings----like--this).

Comment: +1. Of course, this will only work in PHP, not in JavaScript. @cherouvim: Because it does exactly what the OP wants: Match a character if it's preceded by a `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
-(.)
```

Comment: Tried it, it matched -f and -n. Is it possible to match them without the hyphens included in the result?

Comment: Yes it already does this. You are going to use the first capture group which only contains `f` and `n`.

Comment: @Ziggy: Nearly any other current regex implementation except JavaScript's has support for lookbehind assertions. See Wevah's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if by 'match' you mean 'capture' the first character after the dash.

This will match the pattern:

```
m/-[a-zA-Z]/
```

This will capture:

```
m/-([a-zA-Z])/
```

Comment: I think I mean match, I'm not too sure though since I'm new to RegExp. I tried the solution though, and it matched -f and -n. Is it possible to match them without the hyphens included in the result?

Comment: @Ziggy: Yes, you can use `m/(?<=-)\p{Alnum}/g` or `m/(?<=-)[a-zA-Z]/g`